# Less: import css that imports another css with url is not working

Tags: css, webpack, less

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using less@3.8.1

A.css (css file that imports from url)

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro:300,400,600,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin');
```

App.less (less file that imports A.css)

```
@import (css) './A.css';
```

with webpack build, it tries to load

`./https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro:300,400,600,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin`

instead of the css from url.

Stack:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro:300,400,600,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin');
^
Can't resolve './https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro:300,400,600,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin' in ...
```

Summary
A.Less - imports -> B.css - (B.css uses import via url) -> Not working

Answer (score 5):

Less does not automatically switch to a CSS import as a fallback anymore. Try this:

```
@import (css) url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro:300,400,600,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin');
```

To import the `CSS` without it being processed

```
@import (inline) './A.css';
```

or treat the CSS as a directive and import and compile the CSS as Less

```
@import (less) './A.css';
```

Comment: I cannot do this on a `css file`.
This import is in a `css` file from a `node_modules` library.

I am importing a `css file in less file and the css file imports another css through url`

Comment: `A.Less` - imports -> `B.css` - (B.css uses import via url)

Comment: Updated the answer to include other options for importing the css file